# Dropping rows from a CSV file in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I trying to drop two rows from a CSV file and after exploring other similar questions I have not been able to figure it out still. I have tried using pandas and it does not seem to be working and I tried a few functions that people on here said worked for them but I could not get to work.

Here is my code I've ben trying. My output is unchanged with and without trying to drop the two rows.
[image]
The rows I'm trying to drop are the United States and Iowa State rows.

```py
import csv
import pandas as pd

iowa_csv = r'C:\Users\Downloads\Iowa 2010 Census Data Population Income.csv'
with open(iowa_csv, encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    county_col = {'County': []}
    for record in reader:
        county_col['County'].append(record['County'])
    print(county_col)


df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Downloads\Iowa 2010 Census Data Population Income.csv')
df.drop([9, 20])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.drop` does not modify the DataFrame inplace, unless you ask it to.  It returns a new DataFrame.  So, either

```
df = df.drop([9,20])
```

or

```
df.drop([9,20],inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! I just got it working using the following.                                     
df.drop(labels=[9, 21], axis=0, inplace=True)

Answer (score 0):

df.drop(labels=[9, 21], axis=0, inplace=True)

Comment: You should mark the question as solved with the other poster's answer, instead of copying the solution and answering it yourself.